# Exchange Routing agent - check if email address is a exchange shared mailbox using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, email, powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to build a routing agent `dll` for `Exchange 2010`, that will check if the recipient email address is an Exchange shared mailbox (a regular mailbox with multiple full control owner users). If it is, I want to get the email addresses of the owners on that mailbox.

so basically I need two things:

1. Query exchange to check if owners on the specific email address or if shared mailbox have another identifier I can use.
2. Get all the owner's email addresses.

I'm working on visual studio 2013 with `C#`, I found a partial answer with `PowerShell`, but I don't know how to convert it to `C#`.

This is what I got so far:

```
Get-MailboxPermission sharedMailBox@dudu.com | where $_.user.tostring() -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false}
```

This will give me the owners list, but I don't know how to use this in `C#` in a native way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // run over all recipients list
```

foreach (EnvelopeRecipient recp in messageEventArgs.MailItem.Recipients)

```
{
.........
}
```